# Angular and Tables

Tags: angularjs

I'm confused why my `{{item}}` isn't being bound to the Controller's  `data` object.

My HTML is just "{{item}}."

http://jsfiddle.net/rtFtA/3/

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat='items in data'>
      <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <td>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

.

```
function Controller($scope) {   
    $scope.data = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your jsfiddle code by following these steps:

1> select a angularjs library (in Frameworks & Extensions on the left)

2> select no-wrap in head (or body)

3> wrap your code in ng-app, something like

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>...</div>
```

4> add this to js section

```
var myModule = angular.module('MyModule', []);
```

here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtFtA/10/)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me how to make each day a Column, rather than Row? http://jsfiddle.net/rtFtA/12/